# Is it possible to set channel 3-6 as subwoofers on a DBX260 driverack?

Tags: filtering

We have an installation with two different set/pairs of subwoofers, all powered by different amplifiers. Therefore I want to be able to adjust everything independently.

It seems like the only configuration I'm able to get is:

CH1-2 HF
CH2-4 MF (Or LF)
CH5-6 (Sub or LF, if 2-4 is set as MF)

I have consulted Google and the manual without any real success.

My wish is to have the following configuration:

**LH RH LS RS LS RS**, so that I can set parameters for each subwoofer.

(Please feel free to edit this question to make it more useful to others)

Comment: I believe the 260 will not do this, but I must admit that I am not a config-expert on that unit. I do believe that the dbx driverack venue360 will do that. (hence only a comment, hoping that a someone can provide you with an authoritative answer)... good luck.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Such a shame on such a nice unit :( I guess I maybe could use the first pair of woofers on channel 3, using a XLR Y-split, and the second pair on channel 4. But it's an really ugly solution :(

Comment: Splitter is an option which crossed my mind as well, but let's see if you get any answers on this. Agree the 260 is a nice unit... only had the pleasure of using it once before, but that was a pretty basic setup.

Comment: I don't understand why they can't just give you a simple input matrix like Ashly, Sabine etc.  I even have a Peavey VSX26 which gives you an input routing matrix.  Peavey!  So why not?  But yea, I think that the first question is whether the subs need to ALL be independently adjusted or whether they can be adjusted in two groups.  If in two groups then I see no reason to avoid running the amps in dual-mono with the right cable or.. some amps have switches for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a 2x6 preset (eg. low, mid, high), then adjust the crossover settings so that the passbands of the bottom 4 outputs are identical.  Just because the Driverack labels one output MF or LF, and another one SF, does not mean that the frequencies handled by that channel have to match the label...  You can change the crossover frequencies from the initial values.  It's a lot easier when you're using DBX Driveware to control the unit from your laptop.  I've only used the 260 a few times but having used a bunch of other processors, I found the 260 quite confusing to set up.  But I just fired up Driveware to make sure the settings I'm suggesting are accepted by this processor, and they are, so give it a try.

I used to do this on the Driverack PA.. using the MF output to drive extra full range boxes or extra subs.  For example I could do a cardioid sub with the Driverack PA by using the MF as a second set of sub outputs even though it's not intended for that.

Comment: I did this and it works pretty well! Too bad with the labeling though, but as you say, that doesn't matter. It's a solution :) Driveware was a nice recommendation, I installed it and it seems like a sweet tool to make things a bit easier. The interface on the unit is a bit complicated compared to the software. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked!  If I remember correctly there is also a feature of the 260 where you can assign logical outputs (lettered A, B, C etc) to output jacks (1, 2, 3 etc) where this can be used as an output matrix.. but I'm not sure how much control you would get over each output in that case.  With the 2x6 setup you get the most control.